# command line tool for XML digital signing

Tags: xml, command-line, digital-signature, xml-signature

Are there command-line tools for XML digital signing?

I have found one here:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/xmldsiglic.aspx
but it needs .NET Framework and i would prefer it to work without .NET

Answer (score 2):

I propose to use [xmlsec](https://www.aleksey.com/xmlsec/) available on Linux distribution as `xmlsec1` package or as [standalone binaries for Windows](http://www.zlatkovic.com/libxml.en.html).

Here is [a good tutorial](http://users.dcc.uchile.cl/~pcamacho/tutorial/web/xmlsec/xmlsec.html) to get first examples. The concept of templating the XML content with empty nodes allow to create both *enveloped* or *enveloping* signatures.

Answer (score 1):

XmlSecTool from the Shibboleth project, https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/XmlSecTool can sign and verify signatures on XML documents. It's written in Java, but there's a command line shell script that encapsulates it nicely.

Comment: XmlSecTool only support "enveloped" signature. In my case (FATCA IDES !), "enveloping" signature is a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [XML-Signature Interoperability](http://www.w3.org/Signature/2001/04/05-xmldsig-interop.html) report? That lists several implementations. I've only looked at the links for a few of them but the ones that I looked at them seem live and there's a range of licensing and implementation languagues there. Given a library (which some of these are) you should be able to build a command line implementation fairly easily.